# Email Being Blocked Being Sent in Own Domain

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

I'm getting a server when I try to send an email - within my own domain.

The error:

Your message wasn't delivered due to a permission or security issue. It may have been rejected by a moderator, the address may only accept e-mail from certain senders, or another restriction may be preventing delivery.
The following organization rejected your message: 72.38.169.218.

> Diagnostic information for administrators:
>   Generating server: server-4.bemta-12.messagelabs.com
>   info@tkhservices.ca
>   72.38.169.218 #<72.38.169.218 #5.7.1 smtp; 550 5.7.1 Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering.>
>    #SMTP#
>   Original message headers:
>   Return-Path: 
>   Received: from [216.82.249.211] by server-4.bemta-12.messagelabs.com id 19/89-08444-AE166075; Thu, 07 Apr 2016 13:34:34 +0000
>   X-Env-Sender: info@tkhservices.ca
>   X-Msg-Ref: server-15.tower-53.messagelabs.com!1460036071!55681150!1
>   X-Originating-IP: [120.57.226.93]
>   X-StarScan-Received:
>   X-StarScan-Version: 8.28; banners=-,-,-
>   X-VirusChecked: Checked
>   Received: (qmail 22869 invoked from network); 7 Apr 2016 13:34:32 -0000
>   Received: from unknown (HELO ?120.57.226.93?) (120.57.226.93)
>     by server-15.tower-53.messagelabs.com with SMTP; 7 Apr 2016 13:34:32 -0000
>   Message-ID: <32834DBA81FC7476C709FEC5B8303283@tkhservices.ca>
>   From: 
>   To: 
>   Subject: Hello
>   Date: Thu, 7 Apr 2016 22:53:29 +0400
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: text/plain
>   X-Mailer: Sltxykd uahxq 6.9

Any idea with what's causing the issue?

Comment: The log you provided is self-explanatory: "Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering"

Comment: `1.` It's being rejected by MessageLabs. `2.` This is what it says: "Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering". `3.` Adjust your spam filtering settings at MessageLabs or whitelist the sending email address.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks it worked!  Can you write your response as an answer so I may choose it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's being rejected by MessageLabs.
2. This is what it says: "Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering".
3. Adjust your spam filtering settings at MessageLabs or whitelist the sending email address.